# How to use all css classes or code through a variable?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have my css code in a variable styling. I want to use all my classes through this variable. if i write my css code as styles: [`p{color:red}`], then it works. but when i put my code in a variable it gives me error "Cannot read property styling of undefined".

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  styles: [this.styling]
})
export class HomePage  
{   
    styling='';  pagenm='';
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {} 

    ionViewDidEnter()
    {
       let api = 'myservice.php';
       let params = '&pagenm='+this.pagenm;
       this.homeserv.p_serv().subscribe(data=>{
       this.styling = data.css;  //data.css contains css code  p{color:red} div{color:yellow; font-size:18px;}
       this.dcode = data.html;
       });
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `data.css` contain? Can you please update your question with it?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot access the component's properties from its class decorator.

What you could do instead is define the style beforehand:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

const styling = `p{color:red}`;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  styles: [styling]
})
export class HomePage {   
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {} 
}
```

**Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tssxv1**

Comment: ok Now it works. But, i've css code from my service. which i  have called on load of my home page.

Comment: Please edit your question with what you're actually trying to do then.